# <apex:selectlist> not showing right values

Tags: selectlist

I am using Bootstrap and have two apex:selectList next to each other in bootstrap row(6,6). I am using two different variable for values for both of them and initializing them in constructor.The problem is select list show the same values in both of the selectList.

however, when the print variable on page by simply {!value1} {!value2} , then it shows the right values but apex:selectlist shows the same values based on whatsoever is declared first. I did put a command button and rerender the section again, then it shows the different values . but on page load, it pick the same values for both of them , whomsoever is defined first.

Both the apex list shows 180 but the values just under them are different. 180 in first and 188 in second.. 
If I reverse the postion of apex:select list them both will show 188.
[image]

```
<div class="row top1" id="guDiv">
              <div class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: left;">
                 <apex:outputPanel id="genabilityUR">
                        <apex:selectList style="width:100%;" styleClass="selectinline" id="elecrate" size="1" value="{!electricratecurrentselected}" disabled="{!!ratesEdited}" multiselect="false">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!ElectricUsageRate}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:outputPanel>
             </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align: center;">
                   <div class="circle"> > </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: left;">
                  <apex:outputPanel id="genabilityPR">
                        <apex:selectList style="width:100%;" styleClass="selectinline" id="prorate" size="1" value="{!electricrateproposedselected}" disabled="{!!ratesEdited}" multiselect="false">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!ElectricPropsedRate}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code.

Comment: Is this on a visualforce page? If so, you should [edit] your question to include your visualforce code, or a relevant snippet others can use to replicate your issue.

Comment: Yes. It's a VF page.